# foreach list<object> in object

Tags: c#, list, foreach

I want to make a `foreach` for each item in a list. But it doesn't seem to be possible. Or am I doing it wrong?

The C# class Group

```
public int _id;
public string name;
public List<SubGroups> subs;
```

The C# class SubGroup

```
public int _id;
public string name;
```

Normally I would do something like this

```
// make group = all groups
foreach(var g in group)
{
    foreach(var s in group.subs)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

But I can't call the group.subs or at least it won't show. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
foreach(var g in group)
{
    foreach(var s in g.subs)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

You have to use the variable in your outer loop; which is the current variable in the iteration.

Comment: Should have seen that one comming ^^